# Could not compile cuda_convnet error on pylearn2

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pylearn

Im trying to compile a CNN with pylearn2 on windows server 2012. But when my network includes MaxoutConvC01B it fails to compile and gives the error message,

RuntimeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', (GpuContiguous.0), '\n', 'Could not compile cuda_convnet')

Please any help to resolve this issue will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my `theano` and `pylearn2` distributions weren't the latest builds.

update both to the latest development versions.